# Nothing is happening after i cleansed every stone in Solstheim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have finished cleansing every single stone in solostheim but i am not getting a quest prompt, or an arrow on the map. I have googled the issue and looked in many different places but i cant find out what to do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Return to skall the quest should go on normally